# Field in required a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchProperties$Job' that could not be found

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

Developing **Spring Boot JPA Batch XML based** approach. I developed some code and it's started giving me below error.

Could someone please guide me on this error?

Ideally I was expecting JobLauncher and JobRepository instances should be created to be consumed by the application. What else need to configure here?

Error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field studentTestJob in com.its.example.service.HelloWorldService required a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchProperties$Job' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchProperties$Job' in your configuration.
```

**H2Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
@ImportResource("classpath:applicationContext.xml")
@Import(AdditionalBatchConfiguration.class)
public class H2Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    StudentRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    HelloWorldService helloWorldService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(H2Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(H2Application.class);
        ..........
        .........
    }
}
```

**HelloWorldService.java**

```
@Service
public class HelloWorldService {
    private Logger  logger = LogManager.getLogger(HelloWorldService.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    Job studentTestJob;

    public void testMethod() {

        logger.info(" test method in the service called");
        Map<String,String> testmsg = new HashMap<>();
        testmsg.put("KEY1", "value 1");
        testmsg.put("KEY2", "value 2");
        logger.info(testmsg);

        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().toJobParameters(); 
    }
}
```

**testjob.xml**

```
<batch:job id="StudentTestJob">
        <batch:step id="step1">
            <batch:tasklet>
                <batch:chunk reader="studentReader" writer="studentWriter"
                    processor="studentProcessor" commit-interval="10">
                </batch:chunk>
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:property-placeholder/>

    <import resource="testjob.xml"/>    
    <bean id="helloService" class="com.its.example.service.HelloWorldService"/>
</beans>
```

Comment: try to change `id="StudentTestJob"` to lowercase `id="studentTestJob"`

Comment: I second @Patrick, the job id should be `studentTestJob`. Identifiers are case sensitive.